# How to create a new chatroom on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, chat

I saw a question same like my question. There somebody asked same question but when I go in the chat column it show's chat. I go over there then I didn't saw create a new chatroom.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to [join chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) (comes at 20 rep) or [create a chatroom](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) (comes at 100 rep)

Comment: we need how many repuation???

Comment: Did the link you saw in the other question say something like "Let us continue this discussion in chat"? Because the key word in that sentence is "continue".

Comment: Nope, It was a question from a user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a reputation of 13 you don't have enough reputation to unlock the privilege to [join chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) (which comes at 20 reputation) or [create a chatroom](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) (which comes at 100 reputaton).

You need <s>4</s> 6 to 8 approved suggested edits (earns you +2 for each single one) to reach the first chat privilege. That is something you can do on your own without any help (assuming your edits please the reviewers which is relatively easy).

Comment: 8* suggested edits, OP went from 21 to 5 rep today, this question was posted half way through those losses